# Faster way to update in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, sqlplus

I have a table with a recordid column like

```
recordid
----------
1001
1002
1003...
```

and another table where the recordids are saved in a custom | separated string like

```
col1
-------
1001|1002|...
|1003|1001|...
|||1002|...
```

I want to remove all occurrences of some record ids in the second table - for example 1001. Currently I am doing a update using replace from a PHP script but it is timing out due to the volume of records - the second table has 20 million+ records.

Is there any alternative faster way to achieve the same? I am trying to use regular expressions currently but not sure if that will be any faster. Any suggestions/pointers are welcome.

Edit1:
Current code to update - which is timing out -

```
update table2 set col1 = replace(col1, '1001', '')
where  col1 like '%|1001|%'
or     col1 like '1001|%'
```

Comment: Show your query if you want help fixing it.

Comment: What is the relationship between the two tables? Do you want to remove all IDs in the second table that are in the first one?

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to store lists of things in a single column in a relational database. This question is a good example of why.

Comment: @Barmar - I totally agree that it is a bad idea. Legacy code and this is probably the first step towards fixing it

Comment: The current query is just an update statement with replace. Will add it to the post now

Comment: Yes, I want to remove all the ids in the second table that are in the first one.

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of query can't be indexed, so it will have to search the entire table for each pattern. It's guaranteed to be slow on a large table.

Comment: Does the second table contain only that column, or is there another column that uniquely identifies its rows?

Comment: Your `LIKE` pattern is not correct, it won't match `1001|1002` because it requires there to be `|` before the number.

Comment: And if you have a column like `|1001|11001` the query will convert it to `||1`

Comment: @barmar - thanks for pointing - I had it lost in copy paste, corrected it now

Comment: @Littlefoot - there is a unique column on the second table, yes

Answer (score 2):

This is just an example; as there are millions of rows, I have no idea how will it perform, i.e. whether it will be at least a little bit faster than your `REPLACE`. Anyway - have a look, try if you want.

Test case first:

```
SQL> create table first (id number);

Table created.

SQL> create table second (id number, col1 varchar2(30));

Table created.

SQL> insert all
  2    into first values (1001)
  3    into first values (1002)
  4    into first values (1003)
  5    --
  6    into second values (1, '1001|1002|1006')
  7    into second values (2, '|1003|1001|1004')
  8    into second values (3, '|||1002|1007|1008')
  9  select * from dual;

6 rows created.

SQL>
```

As there's an `ID` column that uniquely identifies rows in the second table (as you said in a comment), then it can be used to create a new, *temporary* table which will have its `COL1` column split into rows. `ID` will be later used to bring the remaining values back (in `LISTAGG`).

```
SQL> create table second_temp as
  2  select id,
  3         column_value rn,
  4         regexp_substr(col1, '[^|]+', 1, column_value) val
  5  from second cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  6                                             connect by level <= regexp_count(col1, '\|') + 1
  7                                            ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

Table created.

SQL>
```

The result is then

```
SQL> select * from second_temp order by id, rn;

        ID         RN VAL
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 1001
         1          2 1002
         1          3 1006
         2          1 1003
         2          2 1001
         2          3 1004
         2          4
         3          1 1002
         3          2 1007
         3          3 1008
         3          4
         3          5
         3          6

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now, it is a simple task of deleting values that exist in the first table; check what reamins:

```
SQL> delete from second_temp t where t.val in (select f.id from first f);

5 rows deleted.

SQL> select * from second_temp order by id, rn;

        ID         RN VAL
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3 1006
         2          3 1004
         2          4
         3          2 1007
         3          3 1008
         3          4
         3          5
         3          6

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Let's aggregate the remaining values back to `col1`:

```
SQL> select t.id, listagg(t.val, '|') within group (order by t.rn) col1
  2  from second_temp t
  3  group by t.id;

        ID COL1
---------- --------------------
         1 1006
         2 1004
         3 1007|1008

SQL>
```

Now, what will it be used for? I don't know; you could use it as a CTAS (Create Table As Select) and create a brand new second table. Or, you can truncate the original second table and insert those values into it. Or ... something else.

Comment: appreciate the effort. let me give this approach a try and see if I can work around it. thanks

Comment: I deleted my alternative answer. This approach, or something like it, appears to be much faster.

Comment: I ended up doing a temp table with the values filtered using regular expressions and then a merge of the temp table with the actual one. Still takes a long time but lot faster than before.